# When a website is reachable through an IPv4 address, DNS is tested and working but all domains error out in Chrome what needs to be checked?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-server

I just moved from Digital Ocean to AWS.  My usual setup procedures for the web server I use for experimentation are not working.

I can reach the site through IPv4 but all domains error out and my SSL certificate doesn't show up when tested on SSL Shopper.  DNS appears to be working fine, my firewall is open, SSL certificate installed and NGINX running fine.  When all the obvious things are working what do I need to check?  Or alternately am I missing something really obvious?

This is my setup.

**The IPv4 address brings up the default NGINX welcome screen.**

**Unfortunately all domains error out,**

http://example.com

https://example.com

http://www.example.com

https://www.example.com

**SSL Labs test**

IPs detected correctly on https://www.ssllabs.com/ but in both cases unable to connect to server.

**SSL Shopper test**

No SSL certificates found on https://www.sslshopper.com/.

**In Linux**

**Both ports open.**

firewall-cmd --list-ports

80/tcp 443/tcp

**Nginx installed.**

> Nginx status: Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-03-05 13:48:16
> MST; 2h 33min ago

curl localhost:80 returns 301 redirect which is correct.

**Lets Encrypt SSL certificate installed.**

> Expiry Date: 2021-06-03 18:11:03+00:00 (VALID: 89 days)

**In AWS console:**

**VPC > Your VPCs >**

DNS hostnames: Enabled

DNS resolution: Enabled

IPv6 pool: Amazon ✓ Associated

**EC2 > Instances >**

Instance state: Running

Status check: 2/2 checks passed

Public IPv4 address: 1.1.1.1 (example.com)

Elastic IP addresses: 1.1.1.1 (example.com) [Public IP]

**EC2 > Security Groups >**

Inbound rules

HTTP    TCP 80  0.0.0.0/0

HTTPS   TCP 443 ::/0

**Route 53 > Hosted zones >**

Records

example.com    A    Simple  1.1.1.1

example.com AAAA    Simple  2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) A   Simple  1.1.1.1

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) AAAA    Simple  2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334

**== UPDATE==**

This is what my security console looks like.  VPC > Security Groups > [my id]
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "error out"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to open port 443 for IPv4 in your AWS security group (and port 80 for IPv6).

Comment: Hi Mike, in the AWS console when I select HTTP from the dropdown the Port range is greyed out with 80 in the field.  It won't let me change it.  The same story for https.  I'm at EC2 > Security Groups > [my security group ID]

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to let you change the port number when you select a service by name. What does that have to do with this, though?

Comment: @myNewAccount You need to *add a new rule* to the security group - one for HTTP port 80 and one for HTTPS port 443.

Comment: @MLu As soon as I select HTTP the Port range goes to 80 and stays greyed out.

Comment: @myNewAccount **Add a new rule**. One for HTTP and one for HTTPS.

Comment: @myNewAccount or post a screenshot of the Security Group dialog.

Comment: @MLu  I updated my question to include a screenshot of my security console.  That's VPC > Security Groups > [my id] on Edit inbound rules.

Comment: @myNewAccount you only have HTTPS for IPv6. Add a new rule for HTTPS 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: @MLu ok now I get it.  I just added a rule for HTTPS and HTTP.  I never even thought about that.

Comment: You were right!  That was it!  If you post an answer I'll click it.  You were 100% right.

Comment: You've been commenting on the answer this whole time though...